# MySQL csv import is truncating charecters

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a strange problem. I am using the below code to import a bunch of csv files into MySQL database.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
IF /I "%CD%\" NEQ "%~dp0" PUSHD "%~dp0"
mysql -e "DELETE  FROM software_it.hardware" -u root 
FOR %%f IN ("*.csv") DO (
  set old=%%~dpnxf
  set new=!old:\=\\!
  mysql -e "load data local infile '"!new!"' into table software_it.hardware  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 ROWS" -u root
  echo %%~nxf DONE
)
```

To start off with, the csv file is coming from a CMD output.
I have a field called "UserName" and I have observed the problem only in that field, starngely. 
The username has the format :

> Trilegal\{username}

Now, firstly after the import, the "\" is missing and some of the names have the first charecter missing after the "\".

I am guessing something is wrong because of the presence of this "\". I thought the problem was with my table and hence I used the GUI way of importing. The GUI way imported fine. I used the same table to import using the above code and the same problem is back again.

I am kind of new to MySQL so if anyone can help me understand the problem, it'd be great.

EDIT: Changed to "\" from "/"

Thanks,
SS.

Comment: There's nothing special about `/` in CSV files. Make sure you don't have any extra commas in the file.

Comment: Are you sure? Because when I import the .csv file using GUI in the same table, it is importing just fine. The above code is what is causing the problem. Actually I was wrong and will edit it. It is "\" and not "/". So I am guessing words like \b or \r are making some changes.

Comment: That typo may be why I didn't get the answer last night.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is escape character, by default mySQL treats "\" as an escape character.

Add a line which says `ESCAPED BY ''` in your code and it will not use the default escape parameters.

P.S: Yes I know I am answering myself. Came to this answer after some reading. :D